# mostrar datos de base de datos

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

me encuentro realizando un sitio web en el cual tengo que recorrer ciertas paginas de la misma web seleccionando tipo de documento, notaria, fecha y hora. Al momento de llegar a la pagina de formulario en donde el usuario ingresara sus datos personales tengo pensado integrar una tarjeta la cual toma los datos anteriores los cuales están en una base de datos y los muestre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php

//TRAIGO LOS DATOS DESDE EL URL Y LOS COLOCO DENTRO DE VARIABLES
if (isset($_GET['documento_seleccionado']) && isset($_GET['nombre'])) {
  $documento_seleccionado = $_GET['documento_seleccionado'];
  $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
  
}


// Conecta a la base de datos
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=notaria', 'root', '');

// Recoge el ID del documento seleccionado del formulario
$id = $_GET['documento_seleccionado'];

// Ejecuta una consulta para obtener los datos del documento seleccionado
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM documentos WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$documento = $stmt->fetch();


?>




 
    <div class="card" style="width: 25rem; margin-left: 70px;">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3>Resumen de tu tramite:</h3>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">
        Documento seleccionado: <?php echo $documento['nombre']; ?>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Notaria: <?php echo $nombre; ?>, <?php echo $documento_seleccionado; ?></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">19 de Enero de 2023 a las: 14:00 (podrás reagendar si lo necesitas)</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

el "documento_seleccionado" se supone que son los datos anteriores los cuales voy seleccionando al momento de querer crear el documento (nombre, direccion, fecha y hora) y son a los que quiero llamar para poder mostrar en esa tarjeta.

esperando su ayuda MUCHAS GRACIAS.

Comment: Ya corroboraste que los datos del formulario si lleguen bien al archivo procesador? Que te devuelve un `print_r($documento)` o `var_dump($documento)`

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está mal organizado. Si observas, el `if` debería ser para controlar que esos datos fueron pasados en `$_GET`, pero tú cierras el bloque del `if` y pasas a usar los datos luego, se cumpla el `if` o no. Eso no tiene sentido si quieres escribir un código controlado realmente.

Te propongo lo siguiente, que incluirá, aparte de lo dicho:

- Una forma más clara y limpia de recuperar los valores del `$_GET` usando fusión de null (si usas PHP inferior a 7 debes cambiarlo por operadores ternarios)
- Evitar nombres de variables kiloooooométricos
- Usar un bloque `try ... catch` para controlar los errores relativos a PDO
- Evitar mezcla de contenido PHP / HTML que produce un código difícil de entender, de leer y de depurar. Implementaremos algo parecido a plantillas

Ahí vamos:

```
<?php

    $outPut=array();
    $document=$_GET['documento_seleccionado'] ?? NULL;
    $name=$_GET['nombre'] ?? NULL;
    
    if ($document && $name) {
        try {
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=notaria','root','');
                $sql='SELECT * FROM documentos WHERE id = :id';
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $document, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();
                $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if ($data) {
                    $outPut['data']=$data;
                } else {
                    $outPut['error']='No se encontraron filas';
                }            
        } catch (Exception e) {
                $outPut['error']=sprintf('Error: %s',e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        $outPut['error']='No se recibieron datos desde el cliente';
    }
    
    if ( isset($outPut['data']) ) {
        printf('
            <div class="card" style="width: 25rem; margin-left: 70px;">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3>Resumen de tu tramite:</h3>
              </div>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                Documento seleccionado: %s
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Notaria: %s, %s</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">19 de Enero de 2023 a las: 14:00 (podrás reagendar si lo necesitas)</li>
              </ul>
            </div>',
          $outPut['data']['nombre'],$document,$name);
    } else {
        printf('<p>Ocurrió un error: %s</p>',$outPut['error']);
    }

?>
```